# I want to acquire the relation value with the store when searching for a category in Laravel5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

thank you view my question.

I would like to retrieve information on the tag table relation with the store with many-to-many when searching for a category

I created `Store-table`, `Category-table`, `Tag-table`.
The `store-table` and the `category-table` are connected by a many-to-many relation. The `tag-table` is the same.

I was able to search for categories and get information on businesses that are relation- ed, but I do not know how to get information on tags that are relations with stores.

So, I try this idea. `search categories → get  storeID from relation data→ storeID search → return shop data that hit.`
However, I do not know how to get storeID in the store data acquired by category search

How can I write the code?
please help me.

sorry, bat my English.

**App\Store**

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Store extends Model
 {

  protected $fillable = ['name','location', 'price', 'open_time', 
  'closed_day'];
protected $table = 'stores';

public function photos(){
    return $this->hasMany(StorePhoto::class);
}

public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_store','category_id','store_id');
}

public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'store_tag', 'tag_id', 'store_id');
}

}
```

**App\Category**

```
protected $fillable = ['store_id', 'category_id'];

public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class,'category_store','store_id','category_id');
}
```

**App\Tag**

```
protected $fillable = ['store_id', 'tag_id'];

public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'store_tag', 'store_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

**Resource/Category**

```
class Category extends JsonResource
 {
/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{


    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'store' => $this->stores,
    ];

}
}
```

**web.php**

```
use App\Category;
use App\Http\Resources\Category as CategoryResource;
Route::get("/store/api/category", function (Request $request) {
$search_category = $request->get('category_id');
return new CategoryResource(Category::find($search_category));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot notation to eager load nested relations:

```
$category = Category::with('stores.tags')->find($request->get('category_id'));
```

The tags will then be accessible on each `Store` model related to the `Category`:

```
// create a single flattened array of all the tags
$tags = $category->stores->flatMap->tags;
```

Comment: Thank you so much give me the Awesome answer.